# Bibliography Feature in Word 2007/2010 APA style "et. al" in spanish

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I'm using the APA Bibliography References built-in in Word 2007. When I insert a reference with multiple authors, there is an undesirable "y otros", (which means 'and others' in spanish). That is completely awful. It should insert "et. al.". I even installed a Service Pack 3, which installs APA 5th and 6th edition, but they forget to fix that.

Since I can't user later versions of Word in my PC, i would like to know if there is a fix for it.

Update: I also found this in MS Word 2010

Comment: As far as I know, the only things you can do are (1) postprocess the results of each field to change "y otros" to "et al." *every time you update*, (2), change the language switch in the citation and bibliographic fields to one that uses "et al." (but other localised elements such as "pág." will probably then be wrong, and AFAIK the source's language encoding takes precedence over the field language code), and (3) modify/replace the XSL transform used to generate the field results, and you would need to do that on each PC where you needed to maintain the document. (3) isn't trivial, either!

Comment: Tell me more about 3rd option

Comment: Mmm... perhaps 2nd option it could be also... I suspect that some spanish localized (Spanish Mexico) doesn't have 'et. al' and I should try for Spain

Comment: I haven't tried yet

Comment: @bibadia found a template `templ_str_AndOtherUnCap` in APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl file, but can't find any reference to it in 3082 locale file

Comment: APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl file contains this: `<xsl:template name="templ_str_AndOthersUnCap"><xsl:param name="LCID"/><xsl:variable name="_LCID"><xsl:call-template name="localLCID"><xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:Strings/b:AndOthersUnCap"/></xsl:template>`

Comment: I have posted an Answer that details what to try next.

Comment: do you mind to tell us what editing languages do you use for office? is your system configured with any Spanish locale settings?

Comment: Yes, (Spanish, Mexico)

Comment: I didn't follow this problem for some time ago. Is this problem yet persistent in Office 2016?

Answer (score 2):

This Answer follows the comments made on the Question. It currently assumes Word 2007 and that the .xsl template being used is called APASixthEditionOfficeOnline.xsl, which may be in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style"

This XSL Transform contains a Template called templ_str_AndOthersUnCap. (my previous comment said "templ_str_AndOtherUnCap" which is incorrect.

Open that file using a suitable editor (Windows Notepad works). Save the file under another name (say, "APA6mod.xsl"). Modify the file as follows:

Replace the entire `<xml:template>` called "templ_str_AndOthersUnCap" with the following XSL code:

```
  <xsl:template name="templ_str_AndOthersUnCap" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
      <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
        <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--start: fix to change y otros to et al.-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$_LCID = '3082'">
        <xsl:text>et al.</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:Strings/b:AndOthersUnCap"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--finish: fix to change y otros to et al.-->
  </xsl:template>
```

Adjust "et al." to be the precise text you need. You may also need to modify the LCID "3082" or modify the "test=" part to deal with several possible LCIDs (for Spanish (Spain), Spanish (Mexico) etc.). For example:

```
      <xsl:when test="$_LCID = '3082' or $_LCID = '1034'">
```

adds the Spanish "traditional sort" LCID.

Find the following template:

```
  <xsl:when test="b:StyleName">
```

and replace the template by

```
  <xsl:when test="b:StyleName">
    <!--start: modification-->
    <xsl:text>APA Sixth Edition mod</xsl:text>
    <!--finish: modification-->
  </xsl:when>
```

(Change the relevant texts in there as you think fit. The "APA Sixth Edition mod" text is the one that appears in the dropdown in Word's Ribbon).

Save the file again.

Restart Word, open the document containing the bibliography, then use References->Citations and Bibliography->Style to select the new XSL. Word verifies and loads the various .xsl files when you click that dropdown. If everything is OK, you should now see two APA6 styles - the original one, and the one titled "APA Sixth Edition mod". If you do not see the "mod" one, it *probably* indicates that either the .xsl file is in the wrong folder, or that there is an error in the .xsl file.

If you do the new Style, select it. As far as I can tell, Word should re-evaluate all the Citation and Bibliography fields automatically. You should verify that everything is OK and that you now have the text you want. Remember that you would need this transform on each PC where you need to view/print the document.

Once Word has decided that your .xsl is valid, you can in fact keep it open and modify it while Word is still open. This makes debugging a bit easier. For example, if you need to change the "et al."in the template you modified, you could

- open the .xsl file in Notepad
- modify the "et al." text
- save the file
- in Word, choose a different Style in the dropdown
- in Word, choose the "mod" style in the dropdown

However, if you make a mistake that invalidates the XSL, when you try that last step, your "mod" Style will disappear from the dropdown. At that point you will have to fix the template and restart Word to get it to see your Style again.

I have now looked at the situation for Word 2010, and as far as I can see, the same template is used, the same changes would work, but the default location is different (use "Office14" in the path name rather than "Office12"). I have not looked at Windows Word 2013 or 2016.

As a bit of background, the XSL code to do with LCIDs is trying to establish what LCID (locale ID) it should use. Ideally, we would be able to avoid hardcoding "et al." by writing the XSL so that it said "If the LCID is 3082, use LCID 1033 (or whatever) instead". But Word does not load the regional information for *all regions*, only the regional information for the citation that it is currently processing. So hardcoding of one kind or another is probably unavoidable.

Comment: I created those mod files, with the modifications that you specified with no result. Word doesn't show in the dropdown that "APA mod" that I want. Apparently if I edit the original XSL files could work, I found this when accidentally change some values. Perhaps Word is not recognizing the XSL files that I saved in Notepad as you suggested.

Comment: I have put a copy of a .xsl that works here fine (just tested on Word 2010) at https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tiibeq1mtd8caq/APA6mod.xsl?dl=0 . Just for a few days. Two likely problems are (1) the modified file was not valid .xsl (errors are easy in XSL, and it is hard to verify the XSL without a better tool and (2) the file has not actually saved in the expected location - that can happen if for example you edit in Notepad but do not have permissions to save into the Bibliography\Style folder.  Sometimes better to copy using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Add "y otros" to the auto correct list (`Options>Proofing>AutoCOrrect Options...`) and replace it with "et. al."  You'll have to make some sort of edit near the 'y otros" to trigger the change though.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**: your default editing language is set to Spanish (Mexico) and you added citations specifying the language as `Default` in Create Source or Edit Source dialogue boxes.

The solution might be a lengthy procedure considering that you have already added citations to your documents. I just wonder if you can try first the **Solution for future citations** and update all your citations fields (highlight and F9). If it didn't work for you, as it didn't for me, you will have to go repeating the **Solution for current citations** one by one.

**Solution for future citations**: Set an English locale as the default editing language.

Go to `FILE \ Options` and from the dialogue box's left tabs, pick `Language`. From the `Choose Editing Languages` section, select an English locale from the list, e.g: English (United Kingdom), or add one if no English locale exists by selecting a language from the `[Add additional editing languages]` and click `Add`. Set the English locale as default by clicking `Set as Default`. Confirm your changes.

**Solution for current citations**: Edit every citation's language

Go to `REFERENCES \ Manage Sources`. From the right side list of citations `Current List`, highlight one and click `Edit`. Choose an English locale from the `Language` menu (top right). Confirm your changes, including when Word asks to update the citation in both lists. Repeat this with all your citations in the current list (and the Master list, if you wish).

Comment: You meant "Spanish" locale, that's the language that I want

Comment: No, but let me make it simple. If you want *"et al."*, set the default editing language to one of the **English language locales**, which this is what you want in this question. If you want *"y otros"*, set the default editing language to a Spanish locale, that is, **Spanish (Mexico)**..